# What are good ways to present three-dimensional data to the user in a two-dimensional form?

Tags: user-interface, datatable, language-agnostic

This might seem phrased oddly at first, but let me explain through example. Note that I'm mostly coming at this question from a C# angle, but the question itself is pretty language agnostic.

If we have an array of values to display to the user, something like a `ListView` or `ComboBox` are a good way to present the data to the user. I'm deeming this as one-dimensional data.

If we have a table of values to display to the user, then things like `DataGridView`s work perfect for our needs. I'm deeming this as two-dimensional data.

Hopefully, what I mean by three-dimensional data makes sense now. What is a good way to present this information on a flat screen? At the moment, I'm using a combination of a `ListView` and a `DataGridView` and updating the `DataGridView` as the selected item in the `ListView` changes - but I'm curious if there are other techniques that people have used for this problem.

Comment: Depends entirely on the type of data you're presenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in the chapter "Showing complex data" in Jennifer Tidwell's user-interface patterns book "Designing Interfaces" (O'Reilly, 2006).

For example, Tidwell describes a pattern "small multiples," in which some of the dimensions are tiled across two or three dimensions.

Edward Tufte's books might also be of interest; e.g., "The Visual Display of Quantitive Information."

One name for the pattern you're currently using is "master-detail". I think Tidwell called it something else.